# Want to get all pieces of quoted text from a string and put them into other strings in shell script

Tags: arrays, shell, quote

I have the line

```
var=2 (0 (1 "a" "b")) (1 (2 "a" "b")) (2)
```

and I want to extract both a's and put them into a string x and extract both b's and put them into another string y. This is just an example but the strings inside the quotes can be of arbitrary length. I also had an idea to make an array such that

```
array[0] = a
array [1] = b
array[2] = a
array[3] = b
```

What is the code I need to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to replace string x instead of a and string y instead of b?

kindly open the file which contain the above line through "vi" editor,

```
 :%s/a/x/g   <-- to replace string x instead of string a

 :%s/b/y/g   <-- to replace string y instead of string b
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
# This puts the quoted strings into $1 to $4:
set `echo 'var=2 (0 (1 "a" "b")) (1 (2 "a" "b")) (2)'|
sed 's/.*"\(.*\)".*"\(.*\)".*"\(.*\)".*"\(.*\).*".*/\1 \2 \3 \4/'`   
# This puts them into $x and $y afterwards:
x="$1 $3"
y="$2 $4"
```